# VS 2019 Solution Explorer Commenting

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I am looking for a way/extension to add comments on files, folders and projects in the solution explorer window as a popup or something similar.

The theory is to add small description for some files.

Thank you